# For one to many livestreaming which among jitsi videobridge and janus gateway would be cheaper?

Tags: webrtc, janus, jitsi, janus-gateway

These are what I am talking about:

- https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway
- https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-videobridge

The scalability I am looking for is say 1 to 10k users in a single live stream.

Answer (score 4):

None of those are going to scale to 10k streams out of the box. If all you want is for 1 participant to be seen by 10k people, that is, a one direction broadcast, YouTube or Twitch are better suited for this purpose.

Disclaimer: I'm a developer on the Jitsi team.

Comment: Then how will apps like Periscope or Meerkat be build on webrtc ? I know that Periscope used Wowza Media Server which internally uses RTMP. But given that now WEBRTC is a predominant streaming media choice for people, it should be doable using webrtc as well

Comment: I'm not saying it's not doable. All I'm saying is that none of those are going to work for 10k streams out-of-the-box. You'd have to come up with some way for running multiple instances and balancing the load amongst them.

Comment: Now I am checking out wowza and red5, probably for my type of usecase people prefer those more than jitsi or janus, I read somewhere that wowza is also developing webrtc solution underneath. Let us know your views if you have any experience with any of the above two.

Answer (score 1):

> "None of those are going to scale to 10k streams out of the box."

The question wasn't "which one of these can do it out-of-the-box", it was "which one would be cheaper".

I've been fiddling around for months with both Janus and Jitsi trying to get them to work on a server and I've had no luck, so I can't exactly tell you which one would be cheaper, but I imagine they are roughly similar if you are just relaying the video/audio feed without doing any additional transcoding on the server.

I think what it comes down to cost-wise is probably your setup and configuration. Will you run it on a PaaS like AWS or GCP, or will you set up on some hosted servers and configure the cluster yourself? Which PaaS or server host will you use? How much work are you or your team willing to put into the setup and configuration? Do you even know what you're doing?

Going through a PaaS would save you a ton of work and probably be much more reliable and robust, but will probably be much more expensive. And there are different price ranges among different platforms and services and hosts.

I think the cost will be much more affected by these factors than by the differences between Janus Gateway and Jitsi Videobridge.

But what do I know, I can't even get the ***king things to work on one simple server.